# moz-transform vs max-width / max-height

Tags: css, firefox

Strange... I have the following CSS class, see below.

I encounter different behaviour between chrome / safari and Firefox.
Looks like chrome "renders" the zoom: 3 FIRST, then applies the max-width/height attributes. If I look at the result in Firefox, I see that the image is cropped (top/bottom OR left/right)...like the max-width/height attributes are applied FIRST the the transform is done. Anyone else who has encountered the same behaviour and found a solution to it? I already tried shifting the attributes within the class to see if I get a different result

Thanks!

```
.slideshow-image {
    zoom: 3;
    /* Firefox */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 11;
    -moz-transform: scale(3);
    -ms-transform: scale(3);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `zoom` instead of just `transform:scale`...`transform` works fine in Chrome?

Comment: Good point... I tried several options and now I know :-) Because when I use zoom the zoom is applied first, then the max-width/height is applied so the image is nicely centred on the page AND isn't cropped (which is the result I want with this class... slideshow image... max size, not cropped... centred)